# Additional Audio Jack not recognized - not working

Tags: linux, audio

I soldered an additional 3,5mm Phone connector to my Mainboard. It works fine under Windows, but my Linux OS it not recognizing the additional jack. I guess there is some detect pin in the audio jack (like for SD cards).

When I plug just an unconnected plug into the Main audio jack, the additional soldered jack works fine. But I don't want to connect anything to the main jack. So I would like to know how to simulate "Jack connected" in Linux?

When I compare alsa-info with both (original or additional soldered jack connected):

```
<   Pin-ctls: 0x00:            <-- orig jack connected
---
>   Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT        <-- addidional jack not connected

<   Power: setting=D3, actual=D3
---
>   Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
```

Also 'pacmd list-sinks' shows that the additional jack is not recognized:

```
<       analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
---
>       analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
```

How can I force Linux to use the jack anyway?

Comment: Have a look at `hdajackretask` (basically, you'll have to overwrite the BIOS provided configuration for your codec). ALSA has a very generic way of handling jacks, but it may not be generic enough, so you may have to dig through that, too. Pulseaudio should work once ALSA picks up the configuration. You can use `hda-verb` if you want to directly fiddle with the codec; maybe you can hack it that way if you can't get the configuration to work.